# Plotting multiple columns groupby on multiple plots

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I have data that looks like this

```
ID    value_y   date_x      end_cutoff
1      75     2020-7-1      2021-01-17
1      73     2020-7-2      2021-01-17
1      74     2020-7-1      2021-06-05
1      71     2020-7-2      2021-06-05
2      111    2020-7-1      2021-01-17
2      112    2020-7-2      2021-01-17
2      113    2020-7-1      2021-06-05
2      115    2020-7-2      2021-06-05
```

And I want to plot the following data such that the following are met:

1. Each ID has 1 graph
2. Each graph has n lines plotted (2 in this example; 1 for each end_cutoff)

So, ideally in this example I would have two separate plots both with two lines.

Currently here is the code I have but it plots them all but on the same plot instead of a new plot for each ID.

```
 grouped = df_fit.groupby(['ID','end_cutoff'])
 fig, ax = plt.subplots()
 for (ID, end_cutoff), df_fit in grouped:
     ax.plot(df_fit['date_x'], df_fit['value_y'], label=ID+' '+str(end_cutoff.date()))
 plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- This solution adds the missing pieces into your existing code

1. Format the date columns correctly to a `datetime dtype`, and extract only the date component.
2. Create a number of subplots equal to the number of unique `'ID'` values
3. Get the index of `ID` within `uid` and use that value to index and plot to the correct `ax`

- This option uses [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)
- The format of the x-axis is `'%m-%d %H'` because the time between points is small. The x-axis will auto format depending on the date range.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# dataframe
data = {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'value_y': [75, 73, 74, 71, 111, 112, 113, 115], 'date_x': ['2020-7-1', '2020-7-2', '2020-7-1', '2020-7-2', '2020-7-1', '2020-7-2', '2020-7-1', '2020-7-2'], 'end_cutoff': ['2021-01-17', '2021-01-17', '2021-06-05', '2021-06-05', '2021-01-17', '2021-01-17', '2021-06-05', '2021-06-05']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# set date columns to a datetime dtype and extract only the date component since time isn't relevant
df['end_cutoff'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['end_cutoff']).dt.date
df['date_x'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date_x']).dt.date

# create grouped
grouped = df.groupby(['ID','end_cutoff'])

# create subplots based on the number of unique ID values
uid = df.ID.unique()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=len(uid), figsize=(7, 4))

for (ID, end_cutoff), df_fit in grouped:
    
    # get the index of the current ID, and use it to index ax
    axi = np.argwhere(uid==ID)[0][0]

    # plot to the correct ax based on the index of the ID
    df_fit.plot(x='date_x', y='value_y', ax=ax[axi], label=f'{ID} {end_cutoff}',
                xlabel='Date', ylabel='Value', title=f'ID: {ID}', marker='.', rot=30)

    # place the legend outside the plot
    ax[axi].legend(title='Cutoff', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]